# How to resolve npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL while installing Angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular

I have npm version v8.5.5 and node v16.15.0

When I did:

> npm install -g @angular/cli

I got this error:

> npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL

> npm ERR! Invalid URL

This is the log:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '@angular/cli'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 9ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 10ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I got it resolved using  Example
npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:port
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.example.com:port

Thanks everyone